# How to pass data from Spring controller to JQuery $.post() call

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, spring-boot

After posting data from the Jquery `$.post()` method, I am attempting to return some data which I want to use in the Jquery alert() from a Spring boot 1.5.1 controller method. Currently, the returned data is empty when used in the alert().

Jquery:

```
$('#element').click(function() {
    var formData = $('#element').serialize();

    var posting = $.post( '/update.json?id=${item.id}', formData );
    posting.done(function( data ) {
        alert(data);
    });

    return false;
});
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/update.json")
@ResponseBody
public void update(HttpServletRequest request, 
        Map model, 
        @RequestParam(value="id", required=true) Integer id) {

    // to validation and binding...

    model.put("result", "test");
}
```

Why is the result property not accessible in the Jquery `data` object in the callback?

Comment: To properly display your data you should do 'alert(JSON.stringify(data))' . But in any case the alert should show something like [Object].. So maybe there's some problem in  your controller ?

Comment: @Massimo Yes I suspect the controller method is not setup correctly. The controller receives the data fine.

Comment: Your spring controller should return an object, maybe, as it is a Response Body

Answer (score 0):

Your Controller has a return type as void, that's normal. You can either use a response entity, if you want to set the status:

`return new ResponseEntity<String>("test", HttpStatus.OK)`

or you can return a plain string a well.